# publish the custom action for the first time using Graph API explorer

Tags: magento, facebook-opengraph

I have done the following steps:
1) selected the POST from dropdown.
2) set the url as me/myapp-namespace:want.
3) set Field Name:product and value="my product detail page url".
But still getting the error:
{
"error": {.

"message": "An unknown error has occurred.",

"type": "OAuthException",

"code": 1.
}.
}

is there anything missing there?'

Comment: shouldn't you be posting to /me/namespace:actiontype with parameter 'product' set to the URL?

Comment: what do u mean by setting the url. i have also tried by setting the parameter name to url and then added the product page url as the value of the parameter but nthing happen.

Comment: I mean that the the value of 'product' (assuming that's the name of the action property) should be the URL of your project object - look at the 'get code' link in your app's open graph settings for the action, which will show you a sample curl call to post an action